# How to prove and comprehend $X_0/Y=Z/Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

My question comes from this [video frame](https://youtu.be/9_0S3O23Caw?t=3737) and I will summerize all background knowledge and question here.

### Knowledge

We first have
$$
X \text{ is a normed linear space.}
$$
Then we define
$$
Y=\{(x_j)_j: \lim_j\|x_j\|=0\}
$$

$$
Z=\{(x_j)_j: x_j\in X, (x_j)_j \text{ is Cauchy}\}
$$

$$
X_0=\{(x,x,x,...): x\in X\}
$$
The equivalent class is defined as
$$
[(x_j)]=\{(z_j)_j: z_j-x_j\in Y\}
$$
The norm on the equivalent class is defined as
$$
\|[(x_j)]\|=\lim_j\|x_j\|
$$

### Question

The professor want to prove the claim $X_0/Y=Z/Y$.

### Something I Understand

Apparently,
$$
X_0/Y \subseteq Z/Y
$$
is easy to prove. Because
$$
\begin{equation}
X_0/Y=\{[(x_j)]: (x_j)\in X_0\}\\
X/Y=\{[(x_j)]: (x_j) \in Z\}\\
X_0\subseteq Z\Rightarrow X_0/Y\subseteq Z/Y
\end{equation}
$$

Then how to prove this direction?
$$
Z/Y \subseteq X_0/Y
$$
I can neither understand the proof in the video nor the equation $X_0/Y=Z/Y$ because $X_0$ seems like a subset of $Z$.